# Why is the RGBA colour different to the hex code with transparency?

Tags: css, colors

I'm unsure why these two colours are different. If my assumption is correct, `rgb(255,0,0)` should be the same as `#ff0000` - and since they are the same, should `rgba(255,0,0,0.5)` also be the same as `#ff000050`? And if not, why, and what hex code could match the equivalent RGBA code?

Why does this appear to not be the case? See the example below:

```css
p:nth-child(1) {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
p:nth-child(2) {
  color: #ff0000;
}
p:nth-child(3) {
  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
p:nth-child(4) {
  color: #ff000050;
}
```

```html
<p>One</p>
<p>Two</p>
<p>Three</p>
<p>Four</p>
```

Comment: Each part of a hex code is a 2 digit hex number from 0 to 255 so it should be "80".

Comment: Why 80? Could you provide an explanation?

Comment: 128 in hex is 0x80.

Comment: After some research I've found that 0x means a hex prefix, but how does the trailing 80 equal 128?

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/hexadecimals.html